# Combine multiple requests in in one url

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

My question is if it is possible to send multiple requests into one. For example:
https://mywebsite?college=123&instructor=321
And
https://mywebsite?college=456&instructor=654

And combine them into one with OR statement. If either of requests has anything.

Comment: This feels a bit like a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... could you provide some more context as to _why_ you are attempting to combine these two URLs?  You can combine two requests in a promise, or perhaps your backend allows the combination of several requests in some manner, or you could look into using some GraphQL-like solution, but I feel like perhaps if we understood the specifics there might be a better approach to consider...

Comment: My question is if it is possible to send multiple requests into one. For example:
https://mywebsite?college=123&instructor=321
And
https://mywebsite?college=456&instructor=654

And combine them into one with OR statement. If either of requests has anything.

Comment: The answer to that basic request is basically no-- HTTP is a protocol that takes one URL and sends it a request.  That doesn't mean there aren't backend configurations in which the equivalent resource of both requests could be bundled into a single request, but that's a very different thing.  If you provide some code it is possible that there is a way to accomplish what you want, but if you are truly only interested in this specific approach then I believe the answer is "no".

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking if it's possible to send multiple query params to the server in one request.

If so, the answer is **yes**.

The url would be written as `https://mywebsite?college=123&instructor=321` Notice the `?` to begin the query string with `&` separating the indivdual `property=value`.

Comment: My question is if it is possible to send multiple requests into one. For example:
https://mywebsite?college=123&instructor=321
And
https://mywebsite?college=456&instructor=654

And combine them into one with OR statement. If either of requests has anything.